# Modificar valor do objeto String passado como parâmetro

Tags: java

Preciso mudar o valor de uma variável dinamicamente passando-a como parâmetro por um método auxiliar. Sempre utilizei os valores dos parâmetros passando da direita para a esquerda. É possível alterar a variável da esquerda para a direita:

Campos da minha classe:

```
private String ipAddress;
private String dnsAddress;
```

Método set para atribuir valor à variável:

```
public void setDHCP(){        
    cmdAdress(ipAddress,"address", "dhcp");
    cmdAdress(dnsAddress, "dnsservers", "dhcp");        
}
```

Método auxiliar para tornar o set dinâmico:

```
private void cmdAdress(String address, String type, String adresses){          
    //Isso não funciona
    address = "netsh interface ip set ";

    //Isso funciona mas não me é útil
    //ipAddress = "netsh interface ip set ";

    //restante do código
    address += type;        
    address += " name = \"" + adapterName + "\" ";      
    address += adresses + " "; 
}
```

O valor esperado seria algo assim:

```
ipAddress: netsh interface ip set address name = \"OffBoard\" static 192.168.1.220 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
dnsAddress: netsh interface ip set dnsservers name=\"OffBoard\" static 192.168.1.1 primary no
```

Apesar de não obter erro, o valor dos campos ficam sempre vazios. Estou fazendo algo errado ou exigindo algo que não é da linguagem?

Comment: Você não está passando os atributos em si, apenas cópia do valor deles para o método `cmdAdress`.

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de passar o atributo? Já tentei assim cmdAdress(Object address, String type, string addresses). Também não funciona.

Comment: Só chamando o atributo direto no método, como você fez e comentou que não era útil, mas usando tipos primitivos e String, é a unica forma.

Comment: Então terei que criar dois métodos auxiliares: um para setar cada atributo. Correto?

Comment: Por que não alterar diretamente o atributo da classe? Pra que passar o proprio atributo como parametro pra um método da classe?

Comment: A intenção era deixar o método dinâmico sem ter que duplicá-lo. Os parâmetros são do mesmo tipo, então achei que evitaria criar um método para cada variável ou evitaria ter que criar um switch ou if para determinar qual variável eu estaria tratando.

Comment: Se há necessidade de identificar se é um ipAddress  ou dnsAddress, infelizmente você vai ter que fazer uso disso. Eu faria uso de constantes para identificar o tipo, e passaria ela como um parametro, assim, você consegue tratar com mais simplicidade qual das duas informações está sendo recebida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que seria melhor usar o retorno de função para definir o `ipAddress` e o `dnsAddress`. Deixa a passagem por parâmetro apenas para fazer o input dos dados necessários à função. Segundo o seu exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
final private String TIPO_ADDRESS = "address";
final private String TIPO_DNSSERVERS = "dnsservers";
private String ipAddress;
private String dnsAddress;

public void setDHCP(){        
    ipAddress = cmdAdress(TIPO_ADDRESS, "dhcp");
    dnsAddress = cmdAdress(TIPO_DNSSERVERS, "dhcp");        
}

private String cmdAdress(String type, String adresses){
    String retorno = "netsh interface ip set ";
    retorno += type;
    retorno += " name = \"" + adapterName + "\" ";
    //Não sei de onde viria o adapterName - talvez de uma variável global, mas não é aconselhável - que tal passar como parâmetro também?
    //Se for uma constante, padronize o nome como maiúscula, igual ao TIPO_ADDRESS E TIPO_DNSSERVERS
    retorno += adresses + " ";
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: Da pra usar um `enum` pra ficar organizado

Comment: Sim, poderíamos usar também um Enum e um StringBuilder no cmdAddress, ficaria melhor.

Comment: Entendi. Ficou como a solução que o diegofm sugeriu. Pelo que vi eu estou exigindo mesmo o que não tem na linguagem. Sobre a adapterName, ela vem pelo construtor que eu omiti na pergunta e também já existem dois getters retornando ipAddress e dnsAddress. Estou muito satisfeito com a ajuda. Obrigado.